# Extracting Length of stay from the difference of two POSIXct POSIXt variables in minutes (numeric)

Tags: r, time

I am attempting to convert two time variable columns into a single numeric Length of Stay in minutes column. The class of the columns are:

```
> class(data$`Date of Discharge`)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(data$`Date of Surgery`)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

What code can I use to extract the difference in minutes between these two columns? Thank you :)

Comment: See:  `difftime()`

Comment: nice and simple just how I like it, thank you